# How to update a datatable column value depending on another DataTable column values?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have two data tables

```
DataTable dt1=new DataTable();
DataTable dt2=new DataTable();
```

I want to update one of the column's values depending on other datatable column value.

Eg:

`dt1` contains columns `[setFamilyno] ["HouseNo"] ["Surname"]`

`dt2` contains the same columns

I want to update `[setFamilyno]` column of `dt1 DataTable`.

- if `dt1["HouseNo"] ["Surname"]` is equal to `dt2["HouseNo"] ["Surname"]` then set the value 1 of dt1 DataTable for all such matches in dt1 table. And for next row from `dt2["HouseNo"] ["Surname"]` is equal to `dt1["HouseNo"] ["Surname"]` then set value for `[setfamilyno]=2` for all such matches..

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz0az7c7.aspx) with a [ForeignKeyConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.foreignkeyconstraint.aspx). The help will be enough to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataView view = new DataView(Datatble);
int viewcount = view.Count;


DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "SurNameEnglish", "HouseNumber");
int distinctcount = distinctValues.Rows.Count;

int cnt = 1;
 for (int j = 0; j < distinctcount; j++)
                {

                    string surname = distinctValues.Rows[j]["SurNameEnglish"].ToString();
                    string Housenumber = distinctValues.Rows[j]["HouseNumber"].ToString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < viewcount; i++)
                    {
                        if (Datatble.Rows[i]["SurNameEnglish"].Equals(surname) && Datatble.Rows[i]["HouseNumber"].Equals(Housenumber))
                        {



                            Datatble.Rows[i]["Family"] = cnt;
                            Datatble.AcceptChanges();

                        }
                    }
                    cnt++;

                }

}
```